# Regex replace wildcard substitution

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a lengthy string `rhKNtypd;; Nfgg;g; d;; vyf;f; hdh vfN;N;` and I need to select the **next single character** followed by `N`

So the regex would be selecting `Nt`, `Nf`, `N;` & `N;`

Now I would like to replace `N` with `X` but placed adjacent to the character as in `tX`, `fX` & `;X` respectively so that the resultant string would be `rhKtXypd;; fXgg;g; d;; vyf;f; hdh vf;X;X`

I've found a way to do the select part with this regex `N.?` but stuck at not knowing how to supply the substitute. I would be using this regext solution with the context of JavaScript like this

`text = text.replace(/N.?/g, "X")`;

**Edit: Had to correct this typo: `rhKtXypd;; fXgg;g; d;; vyf;f; hdh vf;X;X`**

Comment: could you add output what you needed ?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you exactly want, especially regarding the end of your example after replacement.

Comment: Do you really want the result to end with `vf;XNX`? Not `vf;X;X`?

Comment: @anubhava That does not return the expected value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want

```
text = text.replace(/N(.)/g, "$1X");
```

The `$1` in the replacement string points to the first (and only) matched subgroup.

Demonstration:

```js
console.log("rhKNtypd;; Nfgg;g; d;; vyf;f; hdh vfN;N;".replace(/N(.)/g, "$1X"));
```

Comment: This does not return the expected `rhKtXypd;; fXgg;g; d;; vyf;f; hdh vf;XNX`, the question is unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You're right, I commented on that point too. I can't see how the text of the question matches the example.

Comment: Great solution, the typo got in the way, Updated the question.